# How to omit directories from Optimized Storage?

Tags: macos, icloud, git

I keep my git repositories in a directory under **Documents** directory, which puts it in the path of iCloud's Optimized Storage. Often, I'll open a git repository to find files replaced with `.icloud` placeholder files. Current workaround is resetting the workspace changes, but I sense this may cause some issues.

[image: Example of replacement]

Is there a way to exclude subdirectories or files from Optimized Storage? Or any another means to deal with this situation? I do not wish to disable Optimized Storage altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to exclude subdirectories/files present in **Desktop & Documents Folders**, if you choose to store them in iCloud and enable **Optimize Mac Storage**.

A possible workaround for your situation could be to move the git repositories to any directory which is not a subdirectory of `~/Desktop` or `~/Documents` directory.

A commonly used subdirectory for storing repositories is `~/Developer`.

Comment: Seems this is the best means unless Apple allows exclusion from Optimize Mac Storage. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a solution in 2023?

Comment: Is there a solution in 2024? 