# Optimize Mac Storage: Keep local copy AND iCloud backup of directory

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, backup, data-synchronization

My active projects in a directory under `~/Documents/`, which puts it in the path of iCloud's Optimized Storage. Often, I'll open a project folder to find files replaced with `.icloud` placeholder files.

**Current workaround** is either waiting for iCloud to re-download my project or resetting workspace changes via git.

Is there a way to force a **persistent local copy**, while still keeping a **backup in iCloud**?

I'm not trying to [omit directories from Optimized Storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321187/how-to-omit-directories-from-optimized-storage), I want the best of both worlds.

Comment: You can do what you want with a dropbox.com account.  I do.  I do have to put the folder inside of my dropbox folder.  I put an alias where the folder was.  Maybe you could make your dropbox folder you development folder.

Comment: I wouldn't use optimized storage with development files.  Get an eternal drive if you out of space or get a larger internal drive if you can replace your internal drive. Use dropbox to backup and a local backup with time machine.

Comment: a little help might be by going to system preferences -> icloud -> iCloud drive options-> untick optimise storage.

Comment: @historystamp I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. I wan't them backed up in my iCloud and not removed from local (the optimizing part). I want a subdirectories in Documents to be persistent.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii what about the giant megafiles that I _do_ want offloaded to the cloud? ☹️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You cannot always have a local copy with a backup in iCloud as well as having the same files be eligible for Optimized Storage.

Either the files are permanently stored locally, or they're eligible for Optimized Storage - i.e. only stored in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround might be to fake last accessed timestamp for the file, or have an Automator script that opens and closes the file.

I'd love to see a proper solution added to macOS for this too.

Comment: Did you verify whether the timestamp method works?

Comment: I can't find any doc on how (often) Optimized Storage scans for big and/or unused files. But I tested [this way of changing modified date](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-change-a-file-s-last-modified-and-creation-dates-on-mac-os-x-494f8f76cdf4). It works fine.